# jqGrid afterSaveCell event not firing

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to determine why I am not getting alert one when I press enter key upon having the cursor inside an editable cell. I am getting the first `"alert1!"` upon entering the cell for editing but I am not getting the alert inside of `afterSaveCell:` after pressing the enter key.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>My First Grid</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 75%;
    }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqueryui/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqueryui/themes/redmond/jquery.ui.theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print' />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='timepicker/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ 
      $("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'php.scripts/customers.get.php',
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['idcustomers','firstname', 'lastname','address1','address2','city','state','zip','phone','email','cell'],
        colModel :[ 
        {name:'idcustomers', index:'idcustomers', width:55}, 
        {name:'firstname', index:'firstname', width:90, editable: true}, 
        {name:'lastname', index:'lastname', width:90, editable: true}, 
        {name:'address1', index:'address1', width:90, editable: true}, 
        {name:'address2', index:'address2', width:90, editable: true}, 
        {name:'city', index:'city', width:90, editable: true}, 
        {name:'state', index:'state', width:90, editable: true}, 
        {name:'zip', index:'zip', width:90, editable: true}, 
        {name:'phone', index:'phone', width:90, editable: true}, 
        {name:'email', index:'email', width:90, editable: true}, 
        {name:'cell', index:'cell', width:90, editable: true}
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        sortname: 'idcustomers',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'Customers',
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        afterSaveCell: function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) {
            alert("alert1!");
        },
        afterEditCell: function (id,name,val,iRow,iCol){
            alert("alert2!");
        }
      }); 
    }); 
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table> 
    <div id="pager"></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user2209542.htm), which uses practically your code, the both alerts will be displayed. You don't wrote which version of jqGrid you use. Probably some problem exist in old version, but not in the last one.

Comment: I am having this same problem with the free-jqgrid 4.7 and jquery-2.1.1 . how can I debug? I see that it is working in your demo but not on my site.

Comment: @BarryMSIH: Could you reload the latest source of free jqGrid 4.9 beta from [the github](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) first of all or to use the [URLs](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit)? If the problem exist that I would ask you to create small demo which demonstrates the problem. I would debug it and would create the fix.